# How to write a Full text search query using JPQL or native query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpql

I am trying to write a Full text search query using native query , Is something wrong with it. Can anyone please correct me.Whats going wrong here

```
@Query(value="select * from table t where CONTAINS(t.* ,"'search*'")",nativeQuery=true)
public List<entity> search(@Param("search") String keyword);
```

Comment: Please include more details about the schema and data that you are querying, and what data you are expecting to be returned from your query.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL server docs on the contains function:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ? Why should this work - have you verified you've indexed the fields you expect this to work on? You've also not defined the 'keyword' search parameter in your query, so the query will be executed literally as "select * from table t where CONTAINS(t.* ,"'search*'")" and might be why you aren't getting your expected results - you'll get no results unless 'search*' is in the search property list  of the full-text index

Answer (score -1):

You must escape internal double quote

Comment: There is no error with the query but its not fetching the required data